# HTML5 Audio -- analyzing output?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html5-audio

Is there a way to directly analyze the output of the content of an audio tag, and use the output? To be more clear, what I want to do is use the sound levels of the audio content to make a ball bounce higher or lower (using html5 canvas) depending on the level of the sound.

For example, it would be really handy if there was something like audioElement.getVolumeLevel(), although I don't know if such a thing exists.

Also, this question is specifically about using the audio element. I am aware of other methods, but I thought that this would probably work best with what I'm doing right now -- and if a simple solution exists, then I'd rather not have to bring extra libraries into my stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox, it's possible but it's not yet standardized as far as I know ( Chrome probably supports it as well ):

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API

Webkit API proposal: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html

And a handful of related articles / demos:

http://ajaxian.com/by/topic/sound

http://ajaxian.com/archives/amazing-audio-api-javascript-demos

Comment: I'm assuming the Firefox stuff only works in Firefox, right? Sucks that it isn't standardized. But thanks for the helpful resources.

Comment: Yeah, a bunch of the FF calls are `moz....` prefixed.  From what I can tell, the API proposal I linked is the proposed standard, but I'm not sure if FF supports it :)  The really annoying thing in this case is that they're entirely different APIs unlike many other things where the only real difference is the `moz...` vs `webkit...` prefix

Answer (score 1):

There are currently three different Audio APIs being worked on, all different and working in various browsers. Nothing is standardised as yet sadly, but it will get there eventually.

Answer (score 1):

You can change volume levels under both Firefox and Chrome like this:

```
var aud = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0]
aud.play()
aud.volume *= 0.5
```

Setting the volume returns the reset level, so for instance if you try it in the JS console:

```
> aud.volume *= 0.5
0.015625
> aud.volume *= 0.5
0.0078125
> aud.volume *= 0.5
0.00390625
```

That lowers the volume... HTH.