# How to use amplitute from audio file to animate an image size?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api, javascript-audio-api

I am trying to animate some images'size with the amplitude of several audio files when they are playing. So when audio1 is playing, image1 has to react from the audio1 amplitude.

I have basic knowledge in javascript, jquery and HTML but I don't have strong skills in these fields. I've tried to find a solution with audio API or p5.js but I don't know how to access to the amplitude audio parameters from my files. I always find some complicated tutorial and I can't understand how to access audio in my HTML file with a simple way.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="images">
        <img id="image1" src="../images/Image1.svg">
        <img id="image2" src="../images/Image2.svg">
        <img id="image3" src="../images/Image3.svg">
    </div>

    <audio id="audio1" controls>
        <source src="../music/audio1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>

    <audio id="audio2" controls>
        <source src="../music/audio2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>

    <audio id="audio3" controls>
        <source src="../music/audio3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/test_AudioVisualizer_02.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

My questions are: What is the best way to access the amplitude parameter in order to change image size? is audio API the best way to acces amplitude or is there other way? I would like to arrive at something like: 
document.getElementById("#image1").style.height = 10*audio1.amplitude;

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you want to play an audio file using JavaScript, and at a give interval gather its amplitude, or what are you looking for?

Comment: I'd like to have something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQRheIe3cH0&feature=youtu.be But instead of using bars, I'd like to use an image that react to the sound's amplitude

Comment: Maybe this could lead to a direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462206/animate-object-by-sound-amplitude

Comment: Or this: https://howlerjs.com/

Comment: Thanks for all these advices. I'll have a look on this. I think I'll try howlerjs. Looks interesting for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found on that topic:
https://dzone.com/articles/exploring-html5-web-audio

It's basically a pretty detailed tutorial on playing and analyzing audio using JavaScript. I have not attempted this myself, but a quick glance on the code makes it seem understandable.

Other than that, a few other links that might lead you to some direction:

- [Animate object by sound amplitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462206/animate-object-by-sound-amplitude)
- ^ Somewhat similar question on SO
- howlerjs.com
- ^ A seemingly easy API for sound playback, even though I don't think it's got analysing features.

Comment: Thank you for all that advices. I'll have a look on all of these. I didn't know about howlerjs